# Rails: Creating a Scope for Last Month

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3.2 app with an Article model that has a field for date.  I want to create a scope that will retrieve all records from last month.  The problem I'm having is that my current scope is not including the first day of the month.

```
# article.rb
scope :last_month, lambda { { conditions: { date: last_month_range } } }

private
def self.last_month_range
  1.month.ago.beginning_of_month..1.month.ago.end_of_month
end
```

When I run this it does this:

```
SELECT * FROM 'articles' WHERE ('articles`.'date' BETWEEN '2013-07-01 07:00' AND '2013-08-01 06:59:59')
```

When I look at the actual results it only starts with the articles with a date of 07-02-2013.

However, if I change the code to:

```
def self.last_month_range
  (1.month.ago.beginning_of_month - 1.day)..1.month.ago.end_of_month
end
```

It does this:

```
SELECT * FROM 'articles' WHERE ('articles`.'date' BETWEEN '2013-06-30 07:00' AND '2013-08-01 06:59:59')
```

In that case it pulls in articles with dates of 6/31/2013.

Can someone please recommend a fix?  Thank you!

Comment: Seems like a timezone issue. What is your rails timezone set to? and the database ?

Comment: My Rails is set to `config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'`, I'm not sure how to check what my database is set to.

Comment: can you try appending UTC to 1.month.ago.beginning_of_month and 1.month.ago.end_of_month
like

1.month.ago.beginning_of_month.utc..1.month.ago.end_of_month.utc

Comment: @HassanJaveed it resulted in the same SQL, and the same result

Comment: I've added an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveRecord does the conversion automatically to UTC, unless you have specified otherwise. You need to convert the range to UTC.

```
def self.last_month_range
  1.month.ago.utc.beginning_of_month..1.month.ago.utc.end_of_month
end
```

Comment: This is buggy. Correct solution below.

Answer (score 2):

I got bit by a bug in the accepted answer:

```
Time.now.utc # => 2015-05-01 01:18:57 UTC

1.month.ago.utc.beginning_of_month #=> 2015-03-01 00:00:00 UTC
```

The problem is that the time is being converted to utc after the month is subtracted.

Here's a correct solution:

```
def self.last_month_range
  Time.now.utc.prev_month.beginning_of_month..Time.now.utc.prev_month.end_of_month
end
```